# Using an F5 server as reverse proxy cache (instead of Varnish)

Tags: 7, performance, caching

Does anyone have any experience, positive *or* negative, with using Drupal behind [F5](http://www.f5.com/)?

Did you succeed or fail?

In either cases, what functionality did you achieve? How far did you get?

Comment: Hello, Jacob Rockowitz; welcome on _Drupal Answers_. For which Drupal version are you interested?

Comment: D6 but I am already using the D6 Pressflow distribution. Though I have never setup a Varnish (or Squid) reverse proxy cache, I am very familiar with the concepts. Using an F5, which is not my decision, has become a real curve ball for me.

Comment: Thank you. I was asking because we have tags for Drupal versions.

Answer (score 1):

I have used F5 as a load balancer with Drupal without issue. We were using varnish between Drupal and the F5 as a reverse proxy.

Pressflow and varnish have been tested well together, F5 is quite a high end bit of kit so I don't know if anyone else has tried it. From what I remember F5 is very flexible so you should be able to get it to work in the same way as varnish (same headers being sent etc).

Comment: Thanks for your response. We have decided to do exactly what you described, use varnish a reverse proxy between Drupal and the F5 load balancer.